# 'starting version 219' bug after the 15.04 update

Tags: startup, 15.04

After update my system to 15.04, I have an error message at the boot: 'starting build 219'.

The bug is known, its recommend to go to console mode and enter this command:

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f
```

But when I enter this command I get an error message:

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

Comment: Same error message here, but after waiting for an unusually long time, the system boots just fine. You might want to wait for a few minutes before interrupting.

Comment: I am having a similar message with GDM and login fails despite I supply the correct passwkrd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may get such an error if your display manager is not sddm.

Running the following can show which display manager you are using :

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

For example, if your display manager is /usr/sbin/gdm, running the following may help :

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm.service -f
```

Comment: How do I do this is my system is unable to boot?

Comment: I don't think this question applies to you if you cannot boot your system. Yours must be a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 8):

I had some similar errors with my system, and I found that it was an error with some `fstab` entries (external drives that were no longer physically connected). I just commented them out and the system booted as usual. Or you can try to reattach missing external devices.

Comment: You f-in beauty! Man I thought I was going to be here all night. SUCKS that something so petty can cause something so serious. In case this turns up in search engines: PID 366 could not find module by name off