# Problem logging in after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upgrade

I've run distro upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 with the release image.
I chose "erase the disk and install Ubuntu" installation. No errors during installation and I'm able to login in normally.

Eventually  I will get this message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean 194728/13557760 files, 947832/54231040 blocks
```

It then dumps me back to the login page. Cycle repeats and repeats, but never boots me into the desktop.

When I boot into recovery mode, I can run fsck from there, and it gives me the same clean message.
However, it does give me the message:

```
 "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

Any ideas what's going on? I've re-run install a few times and get the same thing every time.

Comment: What you say is not an "upgrade"  but a re-install. You can upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10. From what you say you re-installed.Something different with different related things to check ;)

Comment: same error: http://askubuntu.com/questions/631362/error-getting-authority-error-initializing-authority-could-not-connect-no-suc and http://askubuntu.com/questions/614198/starting-version-219-bug-after-the-15-04-update see if any of these 2 can help you fix this.

Comment: It's odd. I updated packages, and now I'm in the desktop.

Comment: Glad to hear it fixed itself :D I wish all problems would fix them self :P

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, and I have no idea why this worked. I booted into recovery mode. Ran fsck. Then fixed broken packages (which downloaded 3 new packages). Resumed boot into the new image. It threw one error, uploaded the details and it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

The fsck message is probably a red herring. You are probably just seeing typical boot noise from the console because there is an issue with your display drivers preventing the X server from starting a display manager.

Glad to hear you got it fixed though. If I had to guess, one of the broken/outdated packages was a binary display driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble after uninstalling a kubuntu-desktop on my ubuntu 15.10 laptop. try reinstall lightdm.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

Comment: I think --reinstall lightdm is not the solution , there may be another reasons.