# Stuck at "starting version 219" on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, gdm

I know this question has been asked before, but I have tried the solutions, and they have not worked. First, I found [this](http://life.wamari.com/2015/03/16/fixing-starting-version-219-bug-in-kubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet-beta/) website about it. I tried the solution it gave:

> sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f

I was thrown an error:

> Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory.

Then I went on to here to look for a solution. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614198/starting-version-219-bug-after-the-15-04-update) thread about it and tried what the user recommended:

> cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

And found that my defualt display manager is /usr/sbin/gdm.

I then tried:

> sudo systemctl enable gdm.service -f

then

> sudo reboot

It didn't work. So, for anyone willing to help, please do. It is literally my first day running linux and I have this issue.