# How to resume the interrupted upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04?

Tags: 14.10, 15.04, partial-upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Previous the upgrade, my bashrc file was modified in order to add some Path configuration.

While executing `do-release-upgrade` everything was fine until a message prompted about the status of the bashrc file and an option menu was displayed.

From the menu, I chose the "compare changes" option and the only difference was my previous modification. No problem.

Here is the problem: I `ctrl-c` and the whole upgrading stopped. After that, I rebooted my computer and from then it is possible to start Ubuntu only in recovery mode.

After logging in (in recovery mode shell) the welcome header message says "Welcome to Ubuntu 15.04" but the "your Ubuntu release is not supported any more" and "new release '15.04' available" warnings still appear.

I've tried to `do-release-upgrade` again but got the "no new release found" message.

How can I finish or re-run the upgrade??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already partially installed 15.04. There is no point in doing a `do-release-upgrade` any-more, and it will naturally say "No new release found".

What you need to do it is the below command which will install the missing packages, assuming apt-get is installed in the first place:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks @daltonfury42, I'm gonna check this because it's the strict answer to my problem. The answer that I posted includes links for further problems that may or may not happen at all.

Comment: `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`

Comment: I have the same problem as @Cerin in that the terminal was closed and now there is a lock that I don't know how to release.

Comment: @BadHorsie, I had to delete the lock file and then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. This question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a).

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me (running this after a reboot) it started off where the upgrade was interrupted.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Also worked for me in an alternative manner:
- reboot into the recovery mode
- in the recovery menu, select "dpkg"
- and it will repair your upgrade and packages.


For how to boot to the Recovery mode of ubuntu, please refer to: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it's solved. For those who have same or similar problem:

In the recovery mode shell: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

It took a couple of minutes and after reboot "starting version 219" message appeared. So I followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614198/starting-version-219-bug-after-the-15-04-update):

> You may get such an error if your display manager is not sddm. Running the following can show which display manager you are using :
>   `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`
>
> For example, if your display manager is /usr/sbin/gdm, running the following may help : `sudo systemctl enable gdm.service -f`

After rebooting, I got "Failed to start user service user@1000.service", then followed [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243304):

`sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`

`sudo update-alternatives --remove-all x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx`

`sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates*`

And now everything is fine.

Comment: Can you please buff up your answer and add the procedere used here, links can change as well as the content you're linking to so your answer can become a dead end.