# 15.10 to 16.04 Upgrade installation interrupted

Tags: interrupts

During the upgrading installation from 15.10 to 16.04.1 the power went off, now the computer cannot launch the OS, so I cannot do anything. What can I do? Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Where does teh boot fail ? What is output to the screen ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/657940/how-to-resume-the-interrupted-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04) solution?

Comment: Actually there are several lines that change in continue. I don't even have the time to read and I cannot perform any kind of command

Comment: Thank you Jose for your advise but Ubuntu don't start at all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

A. Boot your PC with the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

B. Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

C. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a hard drive.

```
    sudo fdisk -l
```

Suppose it informs that `/` is `/dev/sda1`, continue running:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste these lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save File

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Continue running:

nano /etc/apt/sources.list

In the open file delete content and paste these lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save File

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Continue running:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
exit
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure everything is intact. Without knowing more specifics, I suggest reinstalling the boot loader. Possibly a file that is involved in the boot process had been corrupted. First, boot into a live disk, mount your installation, chroot into it, and try to reinstall grub with "grub-install"

Comment: Thank you Kyle for your answer, since I cannot perform any commands how can I reinstall the boot loader? Do I need Ubuntu OS on a physical support?

Comment: You would need to be able to access the computer enough that you could insert a cd/dvd/usb with. Boot into it, find your installation and mount it, chroot into your install, run grub-install. Those are the basic steps, I'll have to direct you towards the wiki for the specific steps to do so.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: You're welcome! If this helped you, would you mind up voting my post as the correct answer please? :)