# Can I resume upgrading Ubuntu version if it's undone?

Tags: 16.10, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade 16.04 to 16.10. If I start downloading packages with `do-release-upgrade` and after some done percentages and I stop the procedure, will I be able to resume it later, even after rebooting? if yes, will it be without any problems with system?

Comment: If you stop it, you will get in trouble. You will probably need to reinsall the system.

Comment: depends if you stopped it while still downloading or already doing the installation?

Comment: if stopped while download I think you can run it again.
if not or if stopped while installation you could look for answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/657940/423684)

Comment: @Pilot6 what if I stop while downloading

Comment: @derHugo while downloading

Comment: It is better in this case. If you are lucky, nothing will happen. And generally it not a good idea to upgrade from LTS to a non-LTS.

Comment: @Pilot6 you think it might or might not cause a problem?

Comment: It may cause a problem but less likely than if you interrupt it when the packages are installing.