# Terminal is showing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS whereas desktop is showing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, what's the issue?

Tags: unity, upgrade, 18.04, unity-dash

Initially, my laptop (hp pavilion) with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS had the problem of no menu, no unity, no launcher, I tried the solution and it didn't work very well so I updated my Ubuntu in hope that everything will be fixed but now, i get the same thing. My terminal is showing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but desktop is showing 16.04 LTS. 
[Here are the photos of both situations.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/oL6QKaLyWJaUAtkk9)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question with a screenshot of both version reports (unless your terminal one is a TTY)? You could consider doing a [clean install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), however you'd lose your programs, documents, pictures, and other data.

Comment: I have added the photos. As I have mentioned, my unity was not working so, no launcher and no terminal, I did the whole update with tty1

Comment: And about the clean install, no, there's way too much files in there.

Comment: Ok, your photo of the login screen shows that you are using Unity Greeter.  That's a bit baffling since 18.04 uses gdm (not lightdm) and some other greeter.  Did you change that on purpose?

Comment: Did the upgrade get canceled while it was running, possibly due to a powercut? If so, perhaps you should try [restarting the upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/657970) while logged in from a TTY.

Comment: After you login, open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T and type `lsb_release -a`. Then update your question by copying and pasting the **text**.

Comment: output of lsb_release -a : No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: output of lsb_release -a : No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: so, for now what has been working for me is that, I had installed Gnome for fun around a year ago and now my laptop is working fine when I log in with gnome environment but the problem persist with unity and the log in screen still shows 16.04. I presume that's because my default environment is unity.