# How can I get past the "Starting version 219" screen with 15.04?

Tags: boot, 15.04, upstart

so I was able to log on to my desktop earlier via the (upstart) option at the Advanced Options for Ubuntu, and I had updates to do.  I ran the updates, and now I am still getting stuck at the Starting version 219 screen, and the (upstart) option will just sit at the Ubuntu loading screen.  I've tried the sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f, and sudo systemctl enable gdm.service -f from the console page, and simply get "Command not found", with no reference to what command is not found.  Advice?

Comment: Are you following [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/620050/344926)?  If yes, could you add the output of the `cat` command to your question?  Press [edit] to accomplish this.  Afterwards, leave a comment @Fabby...